# Show an error (in Visual studio), when someone tries to use STL in a current .cpp or .h file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

In our company sometimes we write .cpp and .h files, which are used in projects for old WM (we use Embedded Visual C++ 3.0 or something for this) and in more modern code (VS 2010).

This Embedded Visual C++ does not support STL.

So if one of developers, who works in VS2010, changes a file, which is shared, and adds some function, which uses std::vector, for instance, on his side everything will be OK, but the build (which is quite long) will fail.

So to see this mistake sooner, I would like to add something like

```
#if defined(%%STL%%)
#error("!!!!")
#endif
```

in all files, which are compiled with old toolset. In this case the developer could see compile time error even in VS2010.

But I could not find what I can put instead %%STL%% there.

Any ideas? Or maybe someone knows a better way how I can do this?

Comment: Remove the headers maybe, or monitor access to them? Or maybe check if any STL header guards are defined?

Comment: There's no better way to educate a programmer then by having him looking at a failed build after a long wait.  Do spend some effort on setting coding standards, important in any team.

Comment: not the best advice :) I need to speed up the work process, not punish for mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a nice solution (at least I do not see pitfalls)

**%%STL%%** should be **_STD_BEGIN**

this macro is used for "namespace std {" in VS stl implementation

Comment: the only problems are that I can use it only in .cpp files and this line must be after ALL #include statements, but I don't see the way to dispose of them, so...

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment to the question, you could go through each of the header files that aren't supported and see what symbols they define for their include guard. Then check for those symbols being defined.

E.G. The Microsoft C++ header `<algorithm>` defines `_ALGORITHM_` so you can check for that:

```
#ifdef _ALGORITHM_
#error("<algorithm> included")
#endif
```

A bunch of these could be collected up and put into a single header file that you could include in each shared source file, at the end.

Comment: Concur. MS only solution - check _ CSTDLIB _ .  vector and algorithm and evertything else I looked at eventually include <cstdlib> which is just a simple wrapper around stdlib.h, but also #defines this macro.  It would be nicer if some core include defined _STL_ or something, but I don't see it.

Comment: Nice idea, but Murphy says that this error will only be triggered at the end of that long build.

Comment: I can do it, but it would be much more preferable to have 1 (or 2) defines, which I can use. for instance, quite many stl files include crtdefs.h eventually. so I could use _INC_CRTDEFS define. But I'm not sure if it covers everything. I asked this question hoping, that someone KNOWS such define (uses it, or just knows VS STL much better, than me) :)

Comment: also I need an define which will work without false positives... I need only the file, which is used ONLY by all STL, but not other files